# Error with my Python code (for Software Engineering, CS5704)

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a Python function that takes a list of integers as input and returns the maximum and minimum values in the list. Here's my code:

```
def find_min_max(nums):
    min_val = nums[0]
    max_val = nums[0]
    for num in nums:
       if num < min_val:
           min_val = num
       elif num > max_val:
           max_val = num
   return min_val, max_val
```

When I try to run this function with an empty list, like so:

```
>>> find_min_max([])
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

What does this error mean, and how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This code right now will produce `IndexError: list index out of range`. Post [mre]

Comment: Please post the full error message, especially include the line of the error

Comment: You would get that error if you did `find_min_max(None)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you actually ran `find_min_max(None)`. Now, you can't get the zeroeth element of a `None` object so `nums[0]` fails.

Even if you did run `find_min_max([])` your code still would not work. This is because an empty list doesn't have a zeroeth element anyway so `nums[0]` would return an Index Out of Range exception anyway.

What you should do is make an if statement before anything happens to check if `nums` exists. If `nums` doesn't, just return nothing.

```
def find_min_max(nums):
    if not nums:
        return
    min_val = nums[0]
    max_val = nums[0]
    for num in nums:
       if num < min_val:
           min_val = num
       elif num > max_val:
           max_val = num
   return min_val, max_val
```

Comment: "It looks like the python interpreter automatically converted your empty list into a None object" The Python interpreter will never do this.

Comment: Sometimes the python interpreter does weird stuff, but here you're completely right. I have no idea why I even thought that.

Answer (score 0):

When I copy your code, I get a different error.

```py
>>> find_min_max([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in find_min_max
IndexError: list index out of range
```

and when trying to pass in nothing, Python will error because that argument is required

```py
>>> find_min_max()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: find_min_max() missing 1 required positional argument: 'nums'
```

only when passing `None` explicitly (or if it's the value of a variable you pass in) will you get that error

```py
>>> find_min_max(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in find_min_max
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

A "subscriptable" object is one where you can use the `[bracket_notation]` (I think just with integers). It probably comes from the math's sequences & series, like if `S` is `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ...`, then S<sub>1</sub> is `1`, S<sub>2</sub> is `1 + 2`, etc., and a<sub>4</sub> is `4` and the general a<sub>n+1</sub> is a<sub>n</sub> + `1`.

So if you had

```py
sequence = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

then

```py
sequence[2]
```

would be a<sub>3</sub> (since in math, indicies start with 1 usually)

Anyways, the way you would fix your code is to make sure the variable is a `list` and that it has a length of at least 1

```py
def find_min_max(nums):
    if not isinstance(nums, list) or len(nums) < 1:
      return None
      # or return -1, -1
      # or raise an Exception
    min_val = nums[0]
    max_val = nums[0]
    for num in nums:
       if num < min_val:
           min_val = num
       elif num > max_val:
           max_val = num
   return min_val, max_val
```